# 'Cannot Resolve Symbol' - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sdk

So I'm following this tutorial on Android for Maps/Location:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/current-place-tutorial#add-a-map

I've managed to fix any issues such as including more compile dependencies in the build.gradle etc. but this last issue doesn't seem to want to go.

I've imported the code from the tutorial but I get the following error:

[image: Error - Cannot Resolve Symbol]

This is the only error left preventing the app from working. I've looked around on Google and Stack Overflow and the common fixes don't appear to work (Such as restarting, 'Invalidate Caches / Restart' etc)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: DId you create a menu in your layout with that ID?

Comment: Hint: error messages are **text** as well. Dont put up screenshots - instead add code and errors as nicely formatted **text** (see [mcve]).

Comment: There was some missing XML code however I'm now getting the 'cannot resolve symbol R' issue

Comment: Don't use PNG for TEXT (esp. when it's code)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a a Gradle clean.

Gradle \ YourApp (root) \ other \ clean